# Server Side C++ http listener with open connection. What happens with thread, when when client is terminated?

Tags: c++, http, server-sent-events, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to implement server open http connection with events using Cpp Rest SDK. I just started to investigate CPP Rest.
I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949072/server-side-event-c-implementation)
with implementation:

```
MyServer::MyServer(utility::string_t url) : mListener(url)
{
  mListener.support(methods::GET, bind(&MyServer::handleGet, this, placeholders::_1));
}


void MyServer::handleGet(http_request iRequest)
{
  ucout << iRequest.to_string() << endl;

  http_response wResponse;

  // Setting headers
  wResponse.set_status_code(status_codes::OK);
  wResponse.headers().add(header_names::access_control_allow_origin, U("*"));
  wResponse.headers().add(header_names::content_type, U("text/event-stream"));

  // Preparing buffer
  streams::producer_consumer_buffer<char> wBuffer;
  streams::basic_istream<uint8_t> wStream(wBuffer);
  wResponse.set_body(wStream);

  auto wReplyTask = iRequest.reply(wResponse);

  wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: a\n",10).wait();
  wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: b\n\n",12).wait();
  wBuffer.sync().wait();  // seems equivalent to 'flush'

  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));

  wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: c\n", 10).wait();
  wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: d\n\n", 12).wait();
  wBuffer.sync().wait();
  // wBuffer.close(std::ios_base::out).wait();    // closes the connection
  wReplyTask.wait();      // blocking!
}
```

I running in debugger, and I never see thread is terminated. When client is aborted connection, still thread is sitting here, as I can see in the VS threads window in the debugger and no breakpoint after wait is happens.
I am concerning to terminate thread handleGet, when client aborts connection. How can I do it?

With connection from multiple clients and knowledge about limit of 40 thread in SDK, I am not sure, how properly terminate thread created by the library.

Comment: Are you sure that it's supposed to be terminated? I would be surprised if the library doesn't use a thread pool and reuses the threads.

Comment: It is likely that the lib uses a thread pool, and reuses threads instead of spawning them per request (which is not efficient). 40 threads is likely to be more than enough to handle thousands of requests. Assuming you do the proper non-blocking programming. Either way you definitely should not mess with that mechanism, if not exposed by the lib.

Comment: I am not sure, that why asking. I connected with 3 clients, and see 3 threads waiting at the end. So, I just want to clarify it.  I've read, that library using thread pool with 40 threads limitation. BTW, I am going to continue process push events, but wBuffer continue to flush, even, if client dropped connection. So, I don't have the signal to stop it.

Comment: freakish, thanks, even if I not put wait in the end, I should poll for new events, with some kind of synchronization, but still I don't see where client connection is broken, so I will able to terminate handle particular client

Comment: Guys, I got 50 threads, after starting and terminating connections. They all waiting. How to get signal when lost connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by checking wReplyTask.is_done(). Removed wait, and processed response in the loop. When client aborted connection, is_done() returns true. Full function:

```
void MyServer::handleGet(http_request iRequest)
{
    ucout << iRequest.to_string() << endl;
    http_response wResponse;
    auto context = iRequest._get_server_context();

    // Setting headers
    wResponse.set_status_code(status_codes::OK);
    wResponse.headers().add(header_names::access_control_allow_origin, U("*"));
    wResponse.headers().add(header_names::content_type, U("text/event-stream"));

    // Preparing buffer
    streams::producer_consumer_buffer<char> wBuffer;
    streams::basic_istream<uint8_t> wStream(wBuffer);
    wResponse.set_body(wStream);

    auto wReplyTask = iRequest.reply(wResponse);// .then([this](pplx::task<void> t) { handle_error(t);  });

    wBuffer.putn_nocopy("id: 35\n", 7).wait();
    wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: a\n", 8).wait();
    wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: b\n\n", 9).wait();
    wBuffer.sync().wait();  // seems equivalent to 'flush'

    while (true)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        
        if (wReplyTask.is_done())
        {
            wBuffer.close(std::ios_base::out).wait();
            return;
        }


        string datac = "data: c\n";
        wBuffer.putn_nocopy(datac.c_str(), datac.size()).wait();
        wBuffer.putn_nocopy("data: d\n\n", 9).wait();
        wBuffer.sync().wait();
    }


    // wBuffer.close(std::ios_base::out).wait();    // closes the connection
     //wReplyTask.wait();      // blocking!


}
```